# How do I change the order of columns in a Julia DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Suppose I have a DataFrame like this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a = [1,2,3], b = [3,4,5])
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a │ b │
├─────┼───┼───┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ 3 │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 4 │
│ 3   │ 3 │ 5 │
```

How do I subsequently change the order of columns so that column `:b` comes before column `:a`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's simple enough but it took a while to dawn on me so I thought I'd post it here:

```
julia> df = df[!, [:b, :a]]
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ b │ a │
├─────┼───┼───┤
│ 1   │ 3 │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 4 │ 2 │
│ 3   │ 5 │ 3 │
```

Comment: If you have columns with numbers as name, it is better to use this syntax `df = df[!, ["b", "a"]]` , Hope this is helpful for future comers!

Comment: What about swapping two arbitrary columns in a df with many columns?

Answer (score 21):

These are the recommendations for DataFrames.jl 0.21 or later.

If you want to be minimally faster you can write

```
df[!, [2, 1]]
```

If you want to update `df` in place you can do it in two steps:

```
df[!, 1], df[!, 2] = df[!, 2], df[!, 1]
rename!(df, [:b, :a])
```

which is yet faster.

Also you can use `select!` like this:

```
select!(df, [:b, :a])
```

Comment: I think the last line is supposed to be `select!(df, [:b, :a])`

Comment: `select!` is smart about not duplicating columns, so you can write `select!(df, first, second, :)` to move two columns to the front and leave the rest unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

By using either `select` or `select!` from DataFrames.jl. For example:

```
julia> select(df, [:b, :a])
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ b │ a │
├─────┼───┼───┤
│ 1   │ 3 │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 4 │ 2 │
│ 3   │ 5 │ 3 │
```